# Custom configuration section with multiple setting tags with name

Tags: .net, configuration, app-config

Can i create a custom configuration section like this below:

```
<configSections>
 <section name="Section" type="XXX.ConfigSection, XXXassembly" />
</configSections>
----------------------
<Section>
 <Settings Name="PriorityOperation">
  <Details Name="A" ProcName="A1">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="X1" Type="Int" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Name="X2" Type="Int" Value="1" />
    </Parameters>
  </Details>
  <Details Name="B" ProcName="B1">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="X1" Type="Int" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Name="X2" Type="Int" Value="1" />
      <Parameter Name="X3" Type="Int" Value="1" />
    </Parameters>
  </Details>
 </Settings>
 <Settings Name="NormalOperation">
  <Details Name="C" ProcName="C1">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="X1" Type="Int" Value="2" />
      <Parameter Name="X1" Type="Int" Value="2" />
    </Parameters>
  </Details>
  <Details Name="D" ProcName="D1">
    <Parameters>
      <Parameter Name="X1" Type="Int" Value="2" />
      <Parameter Name="X1" Type="Int" Value="2" />
      <Parameter Name="X1" Type="Int" Value="2" />
    </Parameters>
  </Details>
 </Settings>
</Section>
```

I tried this multiple time, Mainly 2 errors i am getting
1. The element **Settings** may only appear once in this section.
2. Name is not recognised element with in **Settings Name="PriorityOperation"**

I am able to achieve the inner collection of Parameters but only stuck with **Setting Name="PriorityOperation"** element.

Please tell me if having multiple setting element is possible or not? if yes then how to do it and how to have a Name element with it.

Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, you need to implement a custom configuration handler to deserialize the .config values.

In your particular case, SettingsElement should inherit from [ConfigurationElementCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx)

Check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tw134k3.aspx) MSDN guide through the process.

Hope this help!

Comment: No this is not working. Creating SettingElements from ConfigurationElementCollection not helping me.

Comment: Can you post your section and elements implementation here?

Comment: Problem is solved. Thanks @Miguel for help. This link help me out - https://manyrootsofallevilrants.blogspot.in/2011/07/nested-custom-configuration-collections.html.